# Android library to read QR codes and EAN codes

Tags: android, qr-code, android-library

I want to read QR codes and EAN codes. Can anyone recommend to me a library to do it?

I am interested to know a few things about the libraries:

- Library size
- Works with QR and EAN codes?
- It is posible to modify the library views for capture the codes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Google supplies this for you in the `com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode` namespace. It supports EAN-13 and EAN-8, as well as QR-codes.

An easy tutorial with corresponding [git-repo](https://github.com/varvet/BarcodeReaderSample) can be found [here](https://www.varvet.com/blog/android-qr-code-reader-made-easy/). That should get you up and running in no time. It also links to more advanced examples. You have full control of the capturing views to do what ever you see fit. E.g. place boxes around the codes or what not..

Regarding the library size I'm not sure, other than that it's small (though thats a relative term). Use minify and proguard and your set, if library size turns out to be a problem.